# How can I set up binding context in XAML to a different class?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, syncfusion

I've got this code I'm trying to bind to a class named BandInfoRepository.cs which is located in the same folder as this XAML named PaginaB.I can't see no syntax error displayed on VisualStudio, still the text is not showing(I added backgroundColor just to see if the label was being displayed and they are, but the text isn't).

Maybe it's important to point out I'm using syncfusion's listview.

PaginaB.xaml :

```
           <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="listView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local2:BandInfoRepository}, Path=BandInfo}" 
                ItemSize="100"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
                <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.4*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.6*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Source={local2:BandInfoRepository}, Path=BandName}"
                                BackgroundColor="Olive"
                                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                TextColor="Black" 
                                FontSize="20" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                BackgroundColor="Navy"
                                Text="{Binding Source={local2:BandInfoRepository}, Path= BandDescription}" 
                                TextColor="Black" 
                                FontSize="14"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfListView>
```

And this is the BandInfoRepository.cs file:

```
public class BandInfoRepository
{
    private ObservableCollection<BandInfo> bandInfo;

    public ObservableCollection<BandInfo> BandInfo
    {
        get { return bandInfo; }
        set { this.bandInfo = value; }
    }

    public BandInfoRepository()
    {
        GenerateBookInfo();
    }

    internal void GenerateBookInfo()
    {
        bandInfo = new ObservableCollection<BandInfo>();
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Nirvana", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Metallica", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Frank Sinatra", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "B.B. King", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Iron Maiden", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Megadeth", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Darude", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Coldplay", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Dream Evil", BandDescription = "description" });
        bandInfo.Add(new BandInfo() { BandName = "Pentakill", BandDescription = "description" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DataTemplate you don't set Source in binding normally, unless you want to do some magic. XAML sets DataContext to each item of ItemsSource.

Try:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding BandName}" BackgroundColor="Olive" FontAttributes="Bold" />
```

and remember to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for BandInfo if you want XAML to track changes in its properties

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Syncfusion Products.

We looked into you code and found that you have defined the ItemTemplate wrongly. You can bind the data objects in the underlying collection directly into the view defined in the ItemTemplate property. SfListView itself creates a view for each items in the ItemsSource property and defines the binding context to it.

For your reference, we have attached the sample and you can download it from the below link.

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ListViewSample607957192

For more information about working with SfListView, please refer the following UG documentation link.
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/getting-started

Please let us know if you require further assistance.

Regards,
Dinesh Babu Yadav

Comment: user3512524 already helped me out with the solution and worked out, I'm new to data-binding. Still, thanks for your answer, I'll download the sample you linked and will see if I can improve my code from there.